# 12.04LTS - Can't connect to wireless or wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, wired

I am a new user to Ubuntu, and inherited a laptop with 12.04LTS on it.  Neither wired nor wireless internet works.  I'd like to get both to work.  Here is the output to `ifconfig`:

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:237.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
      RX packets:516 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:516 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:41264 (41.2 KB) TX bytes:41264 (41.2 KB)
```

Can anyone help?  Thank you!!

edit: `lspci -nn|grep -e 0200 -e 0280` shows:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c](rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your network devices from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280

Comment: I've updated the question to show the results of lspci -nn|grep -e 0200 -e 0280
Thanks chili!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please hook up the ethernet cable. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe b44
```

Your ethernet should now be working. Then do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If it is not installed, that's fine, just proceed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and both devices should now be working.